# Get external file and provide as download

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to make a download on client-side for a Google CDN file.

I have some links on my page that when clicked should generate a download. Something like:

```
<a href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js">Link</a>
```

would be sent as a download to the client.

I tried like:

```
app.get('/download/:version?', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.download(data);
    });
});
```

But that didn't do it. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` only supports paths on the local system.

Try using `http.request()`/`http.get()` instead:

```
var http = require('http');

// ...

app.get('/download/:version?', function(req, res){
  // set Content-Disposition header
  res.attachment('prototype.js');

  // transfer the file
  http.get('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js')
      .pipe(res);
});
```